# RxJava test `repeat` on observable create endless loop on tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, rx-java

I have set up my `ViewModel` to repeat an API call endlessly this way:

```
useCase.fireAPICall(params)
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .repeat()
   .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
   .subscribe(::onSuccess, ::onFailed)
```

In my unit tests, I'm trying to mock the API call and check whether or not the `LiveData` inside the `ViewModel` (updated in the `::OnSuccess` method) is updated accordingly.

**Working** unit test that tests a failure:

```
val error = Throwable("")
// Arrange
Mockito.`when`(repo.apiCall(params))
   .thenReturn(Single.error(error))
// Act
viewModel.init()
// Verify
Mockito.verify(postDetailsViewStateObserver)
   .onChanged(Error(error))
```

** Non-working:** f instead, I try to mock a valid response from that API call with:

```
// Arrange
Mockito.doReturn(Single.just(Success(result, list)))
   .`when`(repo).apiCall(params)
```

Then the `ViewModel` `repeat()` generates an endless loop which blocks my unit test without completing it ever.

**Question:** how can we test a `repeat()` situation by checking just the first thing emitted on that observable?

Comment: You have to cut the sequence short in tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a scheduler for `delay` to take advantage of the time in test so e.g.:

```
val testScheduler = TestScheduler()
RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
```

And after that call `testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` so you will move forward by one second. To make it work you should probably also change the order, `delay` should be before the `repeat`.

You need to `setComputationSchedulerHandler` as `delay` is by default uses this scheduler.

Comment: The `repeat` is actually after the `delay`. That was a bad copy-paste. Thanks for the response, it worked!